# When referring to your friend's mother, can you say "your mom"?

Tags: word-choice

If I say “your mom” to my friend, is this sound too intimate? Should I use “your mother” instead? I’m over 20.

Comment: It's OK if you're saying it to a *friend* or to people of your age.

Comment: And it depends on how they habitually refer to their mother when talking to you.

Comment: Just be careful of accidentally implying ["yo mama"/"your mom" joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Yo_mama%22_joke).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Informally or casually,* calling someone's mother a 'mom' is okay. It is okay to tell that to your close friends. Nevertheless, *'mother'* is better to *stay safe.* And, for that sake, why just 'mother,' any informal word (*dad, bro, sis...* and so on) is not advisable while talking to someone who is not your friend or acquaintance.

So, to answer, since your question reads 'friends,' it's okay to use *your mom.*